# How to interpret following S.M.A.R.T values: "ATA Error Count", Offline_Uncorrectable?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have a harddisk (Western Digital) with increased ATA Error Count, I have searched through different posts on different forums, some of them state the HDD is crap, others say the connection (SATA-cable) has problems.

Smart tests itself didn't show problems - raw values are (as far as I can say) good.

Any ideas? I'm also unsure what a worst value of 253 in "Offline_uncorrectable" and Multi_Zone_Error_Rate could mean. As the raw value is 0 there shouldn't be bad sectors.

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD20EFRX-68AX9N0
Serial Number:    XXXXXXXXXXX
LU WWN Device Id: XXXXXXXXXXX
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    2.000.398.934.016 bytes [2,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Aug  7 08:59:50 2019 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (26400) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 266) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x70bd) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   174   158   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       6300
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       129
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2082
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       129
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       15
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       113
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   124   106   000    Old_age   Always       -       26
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 40878 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 40878 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 2054 hours (85 days + 14 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 61 f2 00 00 00 40

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  e3 00 f2 00 00 00 40 00      22:51:53.472  IDLE
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      22:51:52.394  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      22:51:52.392  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 00      22:51:52.392  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      22:51:52.392  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

  ... 4 similar errors are shown here ...
```

Comment: (1) You’re “unsafe”? Do you mean you’re ***unsure**?* (2) We prefer textual data to be posted as text.

Comment: 1) Sorry "unsure" is the right word, edited ...
2) I'm trying to get text representation tomorrow on another computer.

Comment: 2) removed picture

Comment: Any hints on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to run an extended test with

> badblocks -nsv -t 0 -t 95 -t 197 -t 255 /dev/device

Since SMART is read only, badblocks seems to be better for extended tests, since it writes also data - see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/badblocks#Comparisons_with_Other_Programs

This reads the content of the sector, writes pattern 0, checks for pattern 0 and writes the old content of sector. (non destructive mode)
After the whole disk is finished it does the same for pattern 95 and so on.

So as a whole 4 complete writes of the disk are done, lasted 4 days for 2 TB!

With a new SATA cable no changes in ATA Error Count, so I'll use this disk. The cable seems to be broken.

Btw. 253 in "Offline_uncorrectable" is a good value, no idea why Value is lower than worst value, should be at least the same, perhaps some sort of wrong presentation of data.